# Show equivalence with Legendre symbol

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, equivalence-relations

Let $p,q$ be two odd primes for which $p=2q+3$. I want to show that $\left( \frac{q}{p}\right)=1 \iff q=\pm 1 \pmod{12}$.

I have thought the following.

$$\left( \frac{q}{p}\right)=\left( \frac{p}{q}\right) (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2} \cdot \frac{q-1}{2}}=\left( \frac{p}{q}\right) (-1)^{\frac{(q+1)(q-1)}{2} }=\left( \frac{p}{q}\right)$$

So we know that if there is a $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv q \pmod{p}$, then there is also a $y$ such that $y^2 \equiv p \mod{q}$.

But how can we get the desired equality for $q$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $(\frac{q}{p}) = 1.$ Then we have $(\frac{p}{q}) = (-1)^{\frac{(q + 1)(q - 1)}{2}} = 1.$ Note that $q \equiv 1, 5, 7, 11 \pmod{12}.$ ($q \neq 3$ because then $p = 9$) We have $(\frac{p}{q}) = (\frac{3}{q}) = 1$ implies that $(\frac{q}{3}) = (-1)^{\frac{q - 1}{2}}.$ So if $q \equiv 5 \pmod{12}, (\frac{q}{3}) = (\frac{2}{3}) = -1 = (-1)^{2 + 6k} = 1.$ Contradiction. If $q \equiv 7 \pmod{12}$ then $(\frac{1}{3}) = 1 = (-1)^{3 + 6k} = -1.$ Contradiction.

To show the reverse direction, we want to show that $(\frac{q}{p}) = (\frac{p}{q}) = 1.$ Thus, we want to show that $(\frac{p}{q}) = (\frac{3}{q}) = 1.$ We have that $(\frac{3}{q})(\frac{q}{3}) = (-1)^{\frac{q - 1}{2}}.$ If $q \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$ then $(\frac{q}{3}) = 1.$ And thus, $(\frac{3}{q}) = (-1)^{6k} = 1.$ If $q \equiv -1 \pmod{12}$ then $(\frac{q}{3}) = -1$ and $-(\frac{3}{q}) = (-1)^{-1 + 6k} = -1.$ Thus, $(\frac{p}{q}) = 1 = (\frac{q}{p}).$

Comment: I reread your answer. Shouldn't it be $\left( \frac{1}{3}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{4 \cdot 2}{2}}=(-1)^4$ ? Or am I wrong? But if so, how do we get a contradiction?

Comment: $q \equiv 7 \pmod{12}$ so $(\frac{q}{3}) = (\frac{1}{3}).$ And since, we worked out that $(\frac{q}{3}) = (-1)^{\frac{q - 1}{2}}$ we should have that $(\frac{q}{3}) = (\frac{1}{3}) = (-1)^{\frac{6 + 12k}{2}} = (-1)^{3 + 6k}.$ But clearly this is a contradiction as 1 is a square $\pmod{3}$ but $(-1)^{3 + 6k} = -1.$

Comment: I see.. At the reverse direction, we get that $\left( \frac{p}{q}\right)=1$ and then we have that $\left( \frac{q}{p}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{(q+1)(q-1)}{2}} \left( \frac{p}{q}\right)=1$, right?

Comment: Yes exactly right.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem :) Glad to help